# Jenkins CI workflow implementation

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, tibco

I'm trying to set up Jenkins-ci for a project using bitbucket server as a repository . I've already set up jenkins with the appropriate plugins.
I want jenkins-CI to run build scripts ,whenever someone commit the changes to any branch  like master,develop or any feature branch.

Can you please suggest some ideas/best practices which can be used to how to achieve this work flow.If anyone has configured jenkins CI with multiple tibco bw codes in single branch ,please suggest some ideas. We want that build should be triggered only on the changed tibco bw code.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you have specified for "build triggers"?

Comment: @rrirower:- haven't specified anything to build trigger as of now.Just I configured Bitbucket server and Jenkins.And in jenkins we will use Ant scripts for build and deploy activity. If you can give some inputs,how to achieve the work flow it will be really helpful.

Comment: I can only comment on how I use Jenkins with SVN.  I check the "Poll SCM " box and supply a schedule to look for updated source code.  Currently, it's set to look every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Multibranch Pipeline Project in Jenkins 2. Configure your Git Server and add the include branches "master develop"

Then you should add the Jenkinsfile to these branches with the appropriate code to build the project etc..

It is also useful to enable "Build Periodically" in your mutltibranch pipeline job to enable automatic branch indexing.

Here are more information about pipeline scripts in jenkins.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/